# Respond on request with get-parameters or hash

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to get the view for my web application by `jQuery.load()` (the kind of AJAX request). I would like to send URN like `/top?fragment=all_tasks`: here we can understand, what `all_tasks` mean. Unlike this method:

```
Route::get('top/{fragments}', function ($reallyItCouldBeAnyting) {
    return view($reallyItCoudBeAnyting);
});
```

I did not found the examples for respond on get-parameters or hash. How I should to correct below examples?

```
// warning: invalid code
Route::get('top?fragment=all_tasks', function ($fragment) {

    if(Request::ajax()){
        // partial HTML-document without <head> for jQuery.load()
        return view('fragments.'.'.'.$fragment); 
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }
});

// warning: invalid code
Route::get('top?#all_tasks', function ($fragment) {
    if(Request::ajax()){
        // partial HTML-document without <head> for jQuery.load()
        return view('fragments.'.'.'.$fragment); 
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: Use [**$request**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests) to capture a URL parameter. `$request->input('fragment');`. And you will not capture the URL fragment. It is not processed by PHP, just by JavaScript.

Comment: @Valdeir Psr, Thank you for the comment answer! Do you mean that PHP could not capture `#all_tasks`?

Comment: Exactly. PHP can not "see" the URL fragment (`#all_tasks`).

Comment: @Valdeir Psr, O'K, got it. Sorry for one more question: I should to retrieve 
get parameters via `$request->input('fragment');` even if it has not any
relationship with input fields?

Comment: Yes. You can use `Request::input ('fragment')` anyway.

Comment: It's answer! Thank you for the explanations.